# sql multiple join, collection

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have view output like.

V1 with input CE1

```
Costcode    itemcode    costcode
CE1     ITEM1       CE2
CE1     ITEM2       CE3
CE1     ITEM3       --
```

When again if I execute V1 with input CE2

```
Costcode    itemcode    costcode
CE2     ITEM4       CE4
CE2     ITEM5       --
CE2     ITEM6       --
```

When again if I execute V1 with input CE4

```
Costcode    itemcode    costcode
CE4     ITEM7       --
CE4     ITEM8       --
```

When again if I execute V1 with input CE3

```
Costcode    itemcode    costcode
CE3     ITEM9       --
CE3     ITEM10      --
```

How can I get output like

```
Costcode    itemcode    costcode
CE1     ITEM1       CE2
CE1     ITEM2       CE3
CE2     ITEM4       CE4
```

And

```
Costcode    itemcode    costcode
CE1     ITEM3       --
CE2     ITEM5       --
CE2     ITEM6       --
CE4     ITEM7       --
CE4     ITEM8       --
CE3     ITEM9       --
CE3     ITEM10      --
```

How can I get this output in SQL or PLSQL? and how can i Execute View V1 multiple time to get output like this with changing the condition of last columna of costcode. mean just i want tree till the end of last costcode.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code that generates the various result sets.

Comment: Its very difficult to understand from what you have mentioned

Comment: @Sandip As you are new user Please Refer this link First http://stackoverflow.com/help & Please ask question that are useful. Dont ask any question that have no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1:

```
select costcode, itemcode, costcode from v1 where costcode is not null;
```

Query 2:

```
select costcode, itemcode, costcode from v1 where costcode is null;
```